# CSS Photo Gallery wGrid - Gap Problem // Margin around images

Tags: html, css, image, css-grid, image-gallery

**EDITED - 3x3 grid with NO GAPS solved (if images are all same size)  Now, how would I do that for different sized images stored in my computer rather than online?  Should I standardize the images' size BEFORE adding to code, or can is it best to resize them in HTML...I'd think CSS.  When different sized images are included, how can I best get them all to the same size/dimensions?  Object fit doesn't seem to do it..** The JS Fiddle and code has been updated to show the grid with one differently sized image causing problems....  From what I'd seen, a grid like the DOES NOT usually want width/height specified in the HTML but in the CSS?

I'm trying to put a 3x3 photo grid within a grid item (onearticles) which is the main content section for my website.  **Grid-gap, or just gap, for the gallery, is the issue.  I don't know much about formatting images for web design yet, but even with this stock photo, the images have HUGE gaps between them.**  Please help!

I have the images in that 3x3 layout with the simple 
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
             and
   grid-template-rows: minmax(100px, auto);

and have a tried a lot of other "responsive" variations, though, the problem persists.  I don't think "onearticles" and the photo-gallery is inheriting any gaps from parent items, and I know I'll have to figure out a way to make all 9 images be the same size in their "grid," despite them not all having the same dimensions/sizes.  As of now, its a repeated stock image, so same dimensions but that **gap issue is the main problem**

In posting the code in these different places, I see there can be a greater gap between the 1st and 2nd row than the 2nd and 3rd row because of the grid-template-rows: minmax(**100px**, auto); I could just switch it to auto to make those gaps vertical gaps the same, but I don't know how to parlay that into solving the overall gap issue....

My goal is to have the 3x3 photo grid to the left of wrapped text, which I don't think will be that much harder than just making the grid with NO gaps.

I've attached ALL my code below as well as a JS Fiddle.  Thank you for the help and keep being awesome everyone!

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

figure {
 margin: 0px;
}   

    .wrapper {
        background-color: red;
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        max-width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        font: 1.2em Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
        height: 100%;}

    .wrapper > * {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 0px;}

      h2 {
        word-wrap: normal;
      }
    
    a:hover {
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: rgb(28, 224, 238);
    }

.main-head {
  grid-area: header;
  display: grid;
  gap: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  
}
.main-head h1 {
  margin-top: 3vh;
  margin-bottom: 3vh;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.content {
    grid-area: content;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
    gap: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    grid-template-areas: 
        "one one"
        "three four";
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .0);
  }




.wrapper article div{
    height: 100%;
  
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
    border-radius: 12px;

}


.one {
    grid-area: one;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    height: 100%;
  }

.onelineup {
    grid-area: one;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    height: 100%;
  }

.onearticles {
  grid-area: one;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  }

  
#morsecrazy {
    border-radius: 4px;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    margin: 7px 15px 5px 10px;
  }


.onelineup img {
    border-radius: 0px;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    margin: 7px 15px 5px 7px;
    max-width: 90%;
    height: auto;
    }

.ad img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    object-fit: contain;
}




    
/* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 2vh;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}





.three {
    grid-area: three;
    height: 100%;
  }
.three h4 {
    margin-bottom: 1vh;
    margin-top: 1vh;
  }
.three ul {
   list-style-type: auto;
   padding-left: 20px;
   padding-right: 5px;
   flex-direction: row;
  }
.three ul li {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row;
}


.four {
  grid-area: four;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  }


  .fourIFR {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 61.67872568688917%‬;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
  }
   
  .fourIFR-iframe {
     border: 0;
     height: 100%;
     left: 0;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     width: 100%;
  }
  




   

.gallery {
  display: grid;
  float: left;
  grid-area: one;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  gap: 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0px;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 50%;
  padding-top: 0px;

  
}
.gallery__img {
  display: block;
  object-fit: contain;
  padding: 0px;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}


.gallery__item--1 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
}
.gallery__item--2 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
}
.gallery__item--3 {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
}
.gallery__item--4 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}
.gallery__item--5 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}
.gallery__item--6 {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}
.gallery__item--7 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 4;
}
.gallery__item--8 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 4;
}
.gallery__item--9 {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 4;
}












.main-nav {
  grid-area: nav;}
.main-nav ul {
  font-size: 24px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;}
.main-nav ul li {
  padding-bottom: 0vh;}
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;}

.side {
  grid-area: sidebar;
  font-size: 2.5vh;}
.side p {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-left: 4px;}

.ad {
  grid-area: ad;
  padding: 0px
}
.main-footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  padding: 0px;
}








.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "header"
    "nav"
    "content"
    "sidebar"
    "ad"
    "footer";
  }

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: 1.5fr 4.5fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
      "header  header"
      "nav     nav"
      "sidebar content"
      "ad      content"
      "footer  footer";
    }
  nav ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  

  .onelineup img {
    border-radius: 0px;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    margin: 7px 15px 5px 7px;
    max-width: 300px;
    height: auto;
   
    }


  .videoofweek {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 500px;
    display: block;
    object-fit: contain;
    
  }

}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 6fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
      "header header  header"
      "nav    content sidebar"
      "nav    content ad"
      "footer footer  footer"}
   nav ul {
     flex-direction: column;
     }
   .main-nav ul li {
    padding-bottom: 5vh;
  }

  .onelineup img {
    border-radius: 0px;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    margin: 7px 15px 5px 7px;
    max-width: 300px;
    height: auto;
   
    }

}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="main-head">
    <h1>Baseball Website</h1>
 
  </header>
 
  <nav class="main-nav">
    <ul>
   <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="lineup.html">Lineup</a></li>
   <li><a href="articles.html">Articles</a></li>
   <li><a href="vidoweek.html">Vid</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <article class="content">
  
    <div class="onearticles">
   <section class="gallery">
    <figure class=”gallery__item gallery__item--1">
     <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2115874/pexels-photo-2115874.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260" class="gallery__img" alt="Image 1">    
      </figure>
      <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--2">
     <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1787035/pexels-photo-1787035.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" class="gallery__img" alt="Image 2">
      </figure>
      <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--3">
     <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2115874/pexels-photo-2115874.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260" class="gallery__img" alt="Image 3">
      </figure>
      <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--4">
     <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2115874/pexels-photo-2115874.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260" class="gallery__img" alt="Image 4">
      </figure>
      <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--5">
     <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2115874/pexels-photo-2115874.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260" class="gallery__img" alt="Image 5">
      </figure>
      <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--6">
     <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2115874/pexels-photo-2115874.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260" class="gallery__img" alt="Image 6">
      </figure>
      <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--7">
     <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2115874/pexels-photo-2115874.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260" class="gallery__img" alt="Image 7">
      </figure>
      <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--8">
     <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2115874/pexels-photo-2115874.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260" class="gallery__img" alt="Image 8">
      </figure>
      <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--9">
     <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2115874/pexels-photo-2115874.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260" class="gallery__img" alt="Image 9">
      </figure>
   </section>
      <h2>The Lineup</h2>
        <p>Thank you so much for the help.  Can get doing so much more now after what's easily been my biggest impasse thus far!</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="three">
   <h2>Articles</h2>
   <ul>
     <li>Y</li>
     <li>A</li>
     <li>D</li>
     <li>A</li>
   </ul>
    </div>
 
    <div class="four">
     
  </div>
  </article>
  <aside class="side">
    <h2>Lineup</h2>
    <p>C - Dude</p>
    <p>1B - Dude</p>
    <p>2B - Dude</p>
    <p>3B - Dude</p>
    <p>SS - Dude</p>
    <p>LF - Dude</p>
    <p>CF - Dude</p>
    <p>RF - Dude</p>
    <p>DH - Dude</p>
  </aside>
  <div class="ad">
    <p>ad</p>
 
  </div>
  <footer class="main-footer">The footer</footer>
 
   </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wikex004/e650oLak/29/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing but is that what you are looking for?

I simply removed the `width` and `height` of .gallery__img and removed the `padding` of figure.

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

figure {
 margin: 0px;
}   

    .wrapper {
        background-color: red;
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        max-width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        font: 1.2em Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
        height: 100%;}

    .wrapper > * {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 0px;}

      h2 {
        word-wrap: normal;
      }
    
    a:hover {
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: rgb(28, 224, 238);
    }

.main-head {
  grid-area: header;
  display: grid;
  gap: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  
}
.main-head h1 {
  margin-top: 3vh;
  margin-bottom: 3vh;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.content {
    grid-area: content;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
    gap: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    grid-template-areas: 
        "one one"
        "three four";
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .0);
  }




.wrapper article div{
    height: 100%;
  
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
    border-radius: 12px;

}


.one {
    grid-area: one;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    height: 100%;
  }

.onelineup {
    grid-area: one;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    height: 100%;
  }

.onearticles {
  grid-area: one;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  }

  
#morsecrazy {
    border-radius: 4px;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    margin: 7px 15px 5px 10px;
  }


.onelineup img {
    border-radius: 0px;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    margin: 7px 15px 5px 7px;
    max-width: 90%;
    height: auto;
    }

.ad img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    object-fit: contain;
}




    
/* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 2vh;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}





.three {
    grid-area: three;
    height: 100%;
  }
.three h4 {
    margin-bottom: 1vh;
    margin-top: 1vh;
  }
.three ul {
   list-style-type: auto;
   padding-left: 20px;
   padding-right: 5px;
   flex-direction: row;
  }
.three ul li {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row;
}


.four {
  grid-area: four;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  }


  .fourIFR {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 61.67872568688917%‬;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
  }
   
  .fourIFR-iframe {
     border: 0;
     height: 100%;
     left: 0;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     width: 100%;
  }
  




   

.gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-area: one;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
  gap: 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0px;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-top: 0px;

  
}
.gallery__img {
  display: block;
  object-fit: contain;
  padding: 0px;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}


.gallery__item--1 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
}
.gallery__item--2 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
}
.gallery__item--3 {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
}
.gallery__item--4 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}
.gallery__item--5 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}
.gallery__item--6 {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}
.gallery__item--7 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 4;
}
.gallery__item--8 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 4;
}
.gallery__item--9 {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 4;
}












.main-nav {
  grid-area: nav;}
.main-nav ul {
  font-size: 24px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;}
.main-nav ul li {
  padding-bottom: 0vh;}
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;}

.side {
  grid-area: sidebar;
  font-size: 2.5vh;}
.side p {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-left: 4px;}

.ad {
  grid-area: ad;
  padding: 0px
}
.main-footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  padding: 0px;
}








.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "header"
    "nav"
    "content"
    "sidebar"
    "ad"
    "footer";
  }

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: 1.5fr 4.5fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
      "header  header"
      "nav     nav"
      "sidebar content"
      "ad      content"
      "footer  footer";
    }
  nav ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  

  .onelineup img {
    border-radius: 0px;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    margin: 7px 15px 5px 7px;
    max-width: 300px;
    height: auto;
   
    }


  .videoofweek {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 500px;
    display: block;
    object-fit: contain;
    
  }

}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 6fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
      "header header  header"
      "nav    content sidebar"
      "nav    content ad"
      "footer footer  footer"}
   nav ul {
     flex-direction: column;
     }
   .main-nav ul li {
    padding-bottom: 5vh;
  }

  .onelineup img {
    border-radius: 0px;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    margin: 7px 15px 5px 7px;
    max-width: 300px;
    height: auto;
   
    }

}
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper">
  <header class="main-head">
    <h1>Baseball Website</h1>
 
  </header>
 
  <nav class="main-nav">
    <ul>
   <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="lineup.html">Lineup</a></li>
   <li><a href="articles.html">Articles</a></li>
   <li><a href="vidoweek.html">Vid</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <article class="content">
  
    <div class="onearticles">
   <section class="gallery">
    <figure class=”gallery__item gallery__item--1">
     <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2115874/pexels-photo-2115874.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260" class="gallery__img" alt="Image 1">    
      </figure>
      <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--2">
     <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2115874/pexels-photo-2115874.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260" class="gallery__img" alt="Image 2">
      </figure>
      <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--3">
     <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2115874/pexels-photo-2115874.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260" class="gallery__img" alt="Image 3">
      </figure>
      <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--4">
     <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2115874/pexels-photo-2115874.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260" class="gallery__img" alt="Image 4">
      </figure>
      <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--5">
     <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2115874/pexels-photo-2115874.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260" class="gallery__img" alt="Image 5">
      </figure>
      <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--6">
     <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2115874/pexels-photo-2115874.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260" class="gallery__img" alt="Image 6">
      </figure>
      <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--7">
     <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2115874/pexels-photo-2115874.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260" class="gallery__img" alt="Image 7">
      </figure>
      <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--8">
     <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2115874/pexels-photo-2115874.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260" class="gallery__img" alt="Image 8">
      </figure>
      <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--9">
     <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2115874/pexels-photo-2115874.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260" class="gallery__img" alt="Image 9">
      </figure>
   </section>
    </div>
    
    <div class="three">
   <h2>Articles</h2>
   <ul>
     <li>Y</li>
     <li>A</li>
     <li>D</li>
     <li>A</li>
   </ul>
    </div>
 
    <div class="four">
     
  </div>
  </article>
  <aside class="side">
    <h2>Lineup</h2>
    <p>C - Dude</p>
    <p>1B - Dude</p>
    <p>2B - Dude</p>
    <p>3B - Dude</p>
    <p>SS - Dude</p>
    <p>LF - Dude</p>
    <p>CF - Dude</p>
    <p>RF - Dude</p>
    <p>DH - Dude</p>
  </aside>
  <div class="ad">
    <p>ad</p>
 
  </div>
  <footer class="main-footer">The footer</footer>
 
   </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I've been stuck on this for a week but neglected to set anything for "figure" as you did.  That did it.  What I was trying to do was reduce the gap, or margin to 0.  There were big gaps between the images.  

The challenge and need now is how to best create such a grid when the images are different sizes/dimensions AND linked from my computer rather than a website.  How can I best resize/rescale images with different dimensions and sizes for a responsive grid like this?  AND not break out of their border or space?

Comment: Not to just leave these Qs here, but I wanted to fill in and give thanks for the solution!  Now just to resize/fit all pictures.  The breaking out I mentioned was only with a shrunk screen and I know I should know as have it implemented in other sections but am a bit hazy on that important thing.  Plus, I need to go to bed and wanted to fill in.  Can't wait to pore into this tomorrow after work thanks to the help!

The grid is implemented taking up 50% of "onearticle" div and text floated.  Success!  Just need to hopefully stretch the images to their 3x3 spot yet "Object Fit" isn't doing it.

Comment: Dear @TomWike Happy I could help you. Please vote for my answer if it ansered your question. For any further questions please open up a new question as this helps to keep things clear.